# Animation in Java Desktop Application like google chrome

Tags: java, swing, animation, javafx, java-2d

when we click on home page in google chrome, which shows the Apps page in which 4 thumbnail icon appears like google search, youtube, gmail, chrome web store etc. and on the left side there is an arrow to move over the **Most Visited** page. When I click on the arrow, it navigate **Most Visited** page with animation and when I press the arrow of right side , it go back by the same animation.

I have created an application in J2SE (Desktop Application), in which it is required to developed the same animation like google chrome (Web Browser Animation).

```
Note: Current Version of Google Chrome
```

how can we done this? any Example?

Comment: Animation is like a slider , that we often see in jQuery

Comment: *"how can we done this?"* Sounds like animated GIFs, probably in buttons (maybe undecorated) would do it. *"any Example?"*  What's your budget?  (SO is not a code generation machine, in case you are wondering.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I want to done the same in Java Desktop Application.Please if you have any solution provide me.

Comment: *"I want to done the same in Java Desktop Application."*  Yes, I got that bit.  *"Please if you have any solution provide me."*  I already provided it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look these sample libraries and frameworks which demonstrate similar animated transitions:

- [Canned Transitions by the JavaFX team.](http://fxexperience.com/2012/03/canned-animations/)
- [Flows in the JFX-Flow framework.](http://www.zenjava.com/jfx-flow/)
- [Sidebar animation sample.](https://gist.github.com/1437374)